# Dart null safety block me even without dependencies

Tags: dart

## Intro

I have new project.

I have `pub.spec` generated by Android studio official flutter plugin.

Nothing manually added / changed in config.

## Problem

When I run `pub get` I receive error:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 3.1.3.

Because my_app depends on dependencies any which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
```

my pub.spec

```
name: my_app
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.3 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
     - assets/images/icons/
```

## Question

1 How to solve it?

2 What does it means `depends on dependencies any` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `pubspec.yaml` seems messed up by something. You have `dependencies` twice so it does actually attempt install a package named [`dependencies`](https://pub.dev/packages/dependencies) which in fact does exist but are very old and deprecated (and does not support null-safety). Try use this instead:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```